# Distributing different SSH keys to different hosts in one inventory

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-2.x

I have an inventory which contains several hosts. I want to distribute the public part of the SSH keys via Ansible. Each host gets an own key. So far I found the [module `authorized_keys`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html) which can do the general job. However I was not able to figure out how can distribute the different keys.

My `.ssh` directory is like:

```
ls .ssh
hostA hostA.pub
hostB hostB.pub
hostC hostC.pub
```

For one host I could write:

```
- name: Set authorized key taken from file
  authorized_key:
    user: joeuser
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/joeuser/.ssh/hostA.pub') }}"
```

But how can I do this for different hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each key is named after the hostname, as is suggested by your question, you could just do:

```
- name: Set authorized key taken from file
  authorized_key:
    user: joeuser
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/joeuser/.ssh/{}.pub'.format(inventory_hostname)) }}"
```